# why is json lint throwing a parse error

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm retrieving data in php and putting it into jquery with post:

```
$.post("php/myfile.php", function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);

    });
```

When the data comes back, I validate it in json lint. json lint is throwing this error:

```
Parse error on line 92:
...           "story": "<p>Music synchroniz
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

The specific string it's choking on starts out:

```
"story": "<p>Music synchronized many important milestones in John Smith\'s life
```

Does anyone have some insight please as to why this datum isn't valid?

Comment: Remove the backslash before the `'`.

Comment: `\'` is not a valid escape sequence in JSON. See http://json.org/, string.

Comment: Thank you, @ComFreek. I took out the \'s. Now I have a different parsing error, but that part of the problem at least is solved. If you put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: @LauraNMS can you post your full JSON ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backslash ('\') is not valid in JSON format.. it is causing error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but try this:

```
$.post("php/myfile.php", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var json = $.parseJSON(data.replace("\\", ""));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`\'` is according to the diagram below not a valid escape sequence:

[image]

source: © 2013  Ecma International, [ECMA-404 The JSON Data Interchange Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf).